# ListView Grouping in Uwp throws error in CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to list players name under category(Grouping). So I used ListView.
I have a ViewModel class which has Observable Collection of PlayerData and i set this observableCollection to CollectionViewSource . when i try to set CollectionViewSource to ListView ItemSource,it throws error![image]

My Complete Source Code : --> [Project Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EteloV10OLMYlnmmvx38cqFOJ1x7AqZm?usp=sharing)

I also want to Customize the ListView GroupHeaderTemplate . How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign CollectionViewSource [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.view?view=winrt-22621) property to The ListView ItemsSource. please try the following

```
listView.ItemsSource = collectionViewSource.View;
```

One more thing, you have not specificed listview GroupStyle please refer the following xaml code

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ListViewGroup">
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind HeaderText}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

**Update**

```
<GroupStyle x:Key="groupStyle">
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ListViewGroup">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind HeaderText}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupStyle>
```

**Insert above style into GroupStyle**

```
listView.GroupStyle.Add((GroupStyle)this.Resources["groupStyle"]);
```

Comment: how to set this group Style to ListView in c#?

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam please refer to update part

Comment: then , how to set the GroupStyle if my ListView object in c# ?

Comment: Do you mean make GroupStyle in the code behind?

Comment: actually, above code is ListView object in c#. and I just make  GroupStyle in the xaml page resource like your templ `DataTemplate`